# 3D image masking android

Tags: android, bitmap, 3d, masking, porter-duff

I am developing an application on 3D image masking .For this i have different transparent images and placing them in an array .I have searched a lot and finally i haveused PorterDuffXfermode to achieve masking .But i can able to get only one masked image at once .Please look at this below code

```
private void makeMask() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
        Canvas mCanvas;
        for(int i=0;i<maskBitmaps.length;i++){
            //mask image
            Bitmap mask=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), maskBitmaps[i]);
            Bitmap original=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nature);
            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width,(int)height, Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
            Paint maskPaint = new Paint();
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
            maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));      
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, maskPaint);
            maskPaint.setXfermode(null);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            setContentView(imageView);  
    }
```

my desired output like as below image.Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: provide proper image.there is no reference image

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I am having image, but I am not having reputation to upload image, any other source, so that I can communicate with you to send image.

Comment: give me your image link

Comment: upload your image here - http://postimage.org/

Comment: https://lh3.ggpht.com/-WVE2Fk1ANntL9CiHlqpVeFOg7OyGE_XP4czoPSmbnCvm2DpuH3OdxGX1Smc_0TZhFXR=s85 please find above link